# "posts awaiting review" orange counter is way off

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, top-bar

Simple math:

> [image]

4 + 1 = 5, not 21.

I believe there was a recent change counting all posts one can review (except Close queue of course) instead of only suggested edits, but still... there shouldn't be such a big difference.

Comment: Do you have tag filters applied to those queues?

Comment: @A.Webb: It has nothing to do with tag filters.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As of yesterday (April 6, 2017) we no longer show a count for this at all; instead, we *highlight* the indicator if...

- You haven't clicked the review button on the top bar, reviewed any posts, or visited /review in some period of time (currently 60 minutes) *and*...
- ...There are more than a trivial number of tasks waiting to be reviewed (currently 513, or roughly half the median number of tasks normally pending in a given hour - this is subject to change at any time, as the number on which it is based has been all over the map as we've been making changes to the top bar *and* review criteria these past few months).

This isn't ideal, but it's a step up from what we had... And more importantly, it's reasonably *fast* - which can't be said for previously-attempted perfectly-accurate counters. Since it has to run on every page load (and occasionally update *while the page is visible*), being fast is really critical; easy to [make the site completely unusable](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/298541/tag-pages-and-review-pages-not-loading-properly/298546#298546) if we fail to achieve that.

There's also a snazzy drop-down listing the queues, so you can check on what's new without having to leave the page you're on:

[image: drop down list of review queues]

Kudos to Oded for whipping this up!

Comment: Hehe, totally forgot I asked this. Thanks!

Comment: We couldn't forget, unfortunately. There was a reminder, *stuck* to the top of our pages, every time we visited the site. Bloody annoying, so we had to do something about it.

Comment: I just did a double-take: "this feature's been around since 2016???" I assume you meant 2017, though it's too trivial an edit for me to suggest.

Comment: Dammit... Thanks, @Kernel. Now I have to go re-issue some checks.

Comment: I wonder who decided to stick the top bar... hmm... :D

Comment: @Shog9 can you display the queue maximum if any? For example, *191/200*, with a bolder text when close to reach the limit?

Comment: Is it meant to be the case that clicking anywhere on the page removes the highlight? I assume this was only meant to happen when the menu is closed, but literally clicking anywhere on the page will remove it.

Comment: No, that's a bug @DavidG: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347711/review-button-lose-highlight-after-clicking-anywhere-on-the-page

Comment: @Cœur the only queue that has a hard limit is the suggested edits one. Others queue don't have any limit.

Comment: An indicator that doesn't even try to take the number of *actionable* items is not a step up. Removing the numerical indication makes it a step down.

Comment: [Related](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/349946/616460), sorry, I may be making a mess scattering posts all over the place.

Comment: When is this going to propagate to other sites (gamedev.SE)?

Comment: No idea, @Arcane; we *just* finally rolled it out to the Int'l versions of SO, so I'd guess we *could* turn it on on most sites now... But I expect we'll wanna go slowly & catch bugs.

Comment: Do you know what is the threshold for int'l versions? In [es.so] I see the counter in orange with only 2 items in the queues.

Comment: I've added an answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/296736/algorithm-for-review-icon-highlighting/296946#296946) that covers the value on other sites, @fedorqui

Comment: It's very kind of you, Shog9. I translated your answer there in [¿Cuáles son las reglas para que el icono de revisiones aparezca en naranja?](https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2151/83) from Meta ESSO.

Answer (score 18):

See [Adam Lear's response](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/230726/140890) to the [original feature request](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar):

> It is also cached, so may or may not be very accurate depending on the amount of ongoing activity in /review at any given time.

and in the comments below it is the remark that:

> It's the total [number of review items]. It doesn't take individual user actions into account at all at the moment.

So the number is off because it is cached and *not your personal count*.

Providing a personalised count would ask too much of the Stack Exchange servers; the count would have to be recalculated on *every page request*, and depends on the review actions of everyone else. So, as [Shog9 puts it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/191638/notify-users-of-possible-reviews-on-toolbar#comment758002_230726):

> Super-expensive to personalize this - so the alternative is simply *not having an indicator*. Think of it as... A reminder to encourage your peers to review.

Either we have an indicator that's somewhat incorrect, or no indicator at all. On an insanely active site like Stack Overflow that means it is incorrect all the time, unfortunately.

Comment: OK, but still looks weird to me to see e.g. 100 and have only 10. I'll get used to it. ;-)

Comment: For me, the Orange counter used to work well up until about a week ago.  Since then it is an entry to disappointment by showing 20-40 for review after a page refresh upon which I click within a few seconds and are shown maybe 1 or 2.   Also, it is not going directly to the questions to review, but the review categories (as show by the OP).  Perhaps that change is closely associated?

Comment: @wallyk: the indicator behaviour changed yesterday, see the post linked from my answer. It used to indicate only suggested edits, now it indicates review tasks.

Comment: I don't agree with this answer. The counter has always shown the personal counter, not a general counter. Since a few months the counter is off. Maybe the behaviour has changed and now it does not show the personal counter any more? In that case the counter does not make sense any more.

Comment: @BartGijssens: you are confusing two counters. The one in the top bar has **never** shown a personal count. The review page itself *did* show per-queue counters that were personalised, **until recently**. See [Review page does not work as before](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/266000)

Comment: @BartGijssens: this specific question was about the top-bar count, not the review page.

Comment: @Martijn Pieters: I know. I have always experienced the top-bar count as the total of the counters in the review page. At some point it changed. Which is fine, except that it then became a UX problem. I no longer understand the purpose of the top-bar counter any more. Posted a question here: http://meta.ux.stackexchange.com/questions/1693/why-do-we-need-the-review-counter

Comment: why do we bother to show the number at all if we know that it is mostly wrong? Why don't we just display an exclamation mark, or similar, to notify users that there are things to review?

Comment: This is horrible UI. The number should reflect what its tooltip says: the total **number of posts awaiting review** (across all queues, regardless of site, i.e., including S.O.). And the number should disappear when the count is (should be!) zero. Anything less than this is, well just **broken UI**.