# Don't show me a review indicator in the top nav bar if I can't review

Tags: bug, review-queues, suggested-edits

A number of times, there's been a little orange badge type indicator that's popped up on the top nav bar between my rep count and the 'review' button. It has been linked to the suggested edits queue for me, but I imagine that may vary depending on your rep.

[image]

Upon clicking it, and being taken to the suggested edits review queue, I am then reminded that I've already done my daily limit of 20, and can't do any more. This is irritating, to say the least. It's not a bad mechanic, but it needs fixing.

---

This question is not really a duplicate of ["posts awaiting review" orange counter is way off](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off). I am not disputing the accuracy of the number shown (and in my experience it has been very accurate of the number of edits available to other users) but the fact I should not be shown it at all.

Comment: I'm not sure that should really be called a bug, instead of a feature-request.

Comment: it's certainly not expected behaviour.. I'm not sure exactly what criteria you have here though, so feel free to edit if that is indeed the case.

Comment: [tag:Status-bydesign]

Comment: The point of the answer in the duplicate is that the number isn't personalized and doing so is extremely expensive. Not showing the number if you have no more reviews *is* a personalized view. It is not a bug, the feature to hide that number doesn't exist.

Comment: @rene As a feature request, hiding the number if you have no more reviews would be much less expensive than personalizing the number itself, right? Wouldn't it be an on/off value that gets flipped once per day per user upon the last review, then cached until it gets flipped back at 0:00 UTC the next day?

Comment: @MaximillianLaumeister well, maybe ... but so far the SE dev team didn't seem to be eager to get that on/off thingy implemented then. But this question is a bug report so that would have to change then.