# When does the review button light up and when does it not?

Tags: support, review-queues, top-bar

Sometimes when I browse through SO and notices that the review button lights up in orange:

[image]

Then I go to another page and it does not light up:

[image]

Other times when I go to another page, it stays at the same state as before. Whether or not the review button changes state seems quite random. When will it light up exactly? Is it when the review queue numbers updates? Then why sometimes it goes back to normal (grey color) again?

Note that I am not clicking on the button or anything, which will normally change it to the "not light up" state.

Comment: It seems to be a bug that sometimes it thinks it's open when it isn't. Regardless of the highlight when the page loads, it is always highlighted when the button is clicked. What I noticed, however, is that clicking again to close the dropdown doesn't work if the button was highlighted originally.

Comment: Not sure whether it's a bug or not. It's just always highlighted on page load, but any page interaction at all clears the highlight. It's the classes `-link _highlighted-reviews` that cause it to be orange. I guess some JS is removing it. Perhaps it's to do with the new dropdown menu.

Comment: @Sweeper Did you fail any audit while reviewing?

Comment: I am not an active reviewer. I have not reviewed anything ever since the new nav bar. @JeruLuke

Comment: I thought the site was subliminally trying to make me review things, I never considered the possibility that it may be a bug

Comment: Perhaps it means that the question you're currently browsing is the subject of an active review?

Comment: I believe it's active if there are new reviews since your last visit. However, if you click anywhere on the website, the highlighting is gone (it also has a class `_highlighted-reviews` while light is up).

Comment: This is what is supposedly implemented https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/792066, there seems to be a bug that makes the highlight to be consistently removed upon clicking any element https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/347711/792066

Comment: @cybermonkey I don't think so. I tested it on a post with a pending suggested edit and a question which was in the First Posts review queue and it didn't light up.

Answer (score 33):

[The exact criteria is:](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/792066)

> - You haven't clicked the review button on the top bar, reviewed any posts, or visited /review in some period of time (currently 60
>     minutes) *and*...
> - ...There are more than a trivial number of tasks waiting to be reviewed (currently 513, or roughly half the median number of tasks
>     normally pending in a given hour - this is subject to change at any
>     time, as the number on which it is based has been all over the map as
>     we've been making changes to the top bar *and* review criteria these
>     past few months).

Basically, no reviews in the last 60 minutes and there are more than 513 tasks waiting.

Comment: I assume the threshold number is either not used or much lower on the smaller sites.

Comment: @DanNeely if you read the post, Shog seems to suggest that it would be a per-site preference.

Comment: Do any other sites have the latest topbar yet? I don't see a review button at all on any other site.

Comment: @Scott no, SO is usually the first to get these experiments.

Comment: OK, so my point is that "the threshold number is either not used or much lower on the smaller sites"  and "it would be a per-site preference" are referring to functionality that doesn't exist (yet).