# Review button lose highlight after clicking anywhere on the page

Tags: bug, review-queues, design, top-bar

If the review button is "highlighted" according to [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653/792066), it shouldn't lose the orange-y color unless I click it or do some review. Well, it lose the `_highlighted-reviews` class every time I click something. Anything.

I couldn't find what actually triggered the class suppression, but I could easily reproduce it:

- Make sure that review is orange.
- Click anywhere in the page (if you click links, you will notice it will lose the highlight before loading the next page, but is not necessary to do so as any element will trigger the issue)

This is not related [to this other question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347684/when-does-the-review-button-light-up-and-when-does-it-not?noredirect=1&lq=1) where the user is wondering what are the conditions for the notification to light up.

Comment: Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347684/when-does-the-review-button-light-up-and-when-does-it-not

Comment: @jmattheis obviously no. One is asking for what is the conditions for the icon to be highlighted, this one is about the behavior of the icon losing the highlight after clicking any non-/review element.

Comment: @Makyen how can you close a specific bug report with a reproducible behavior against a support question asking what are the triggers that keep the highlight on/off. That support question doesn't even  mention of my specific behavior.

Comment: @Braiam, You have a point. I've retracted my cv.

Comment: Why are people trying to close this as a duplicate? The linked question is asking why the icon lights up, this question is pointing out a bug with the feature. Even [Shog9 confirmed this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252843/posts-awaiting-review-orange-counter-is-way-off/346653?noredirect=1#comment465195_346653)

Comment: @DavidG because *reasons*