# Provide notification when there are items in review queue

Tags: feature-request, review-queues

I am relatively new to SO (<10 months and about 500 reputation points) so it is no surprise that I am still in the *getting-used-to-the-site* stage. I am fascinated with the idea that everyone here above 15 rep is able to contribute to the quality of posts.

As far as I understand Documentation review is open to users with >100 rep which I guess is a lot of users.

Triage, First posts, and Late Answer queues are available after 500 rep which means that a significantly lesser number of users are available to review and clear the queue.

Further review queues open up at 2k and 3k rep, which again means that even lesser number of users are there to clear an even larger queue (as of now 7.8k in Close vote queues)

**The question**

Would not these numbers come down if there was some kind of notification (like the notification we get when we have a reputation change, or when we have a reply to a comment) when there are items in the queue that can be processed by the user?

Comment: The review icon changes its color to orange when there are items in review. In Meta the queue is usually empty, but on SO it's always full and you can always review posts because of the huge traffic and tons of LQ content

Comment: @AlonEitan Maybe you are right. But you see, I did not even notice that the review button changes color (I am not sure it does; I have reviewed 20 items so will have to wait for some time now to check if that is true). On the other hand, the notification I got for your comment is more eye-catching. Something like that would keep users more attentive towards contributing to the community

Comment: That is correct, it takes some time for a review to finish, specifically when it comes to flagging a question for closure, some [popular suggestion](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/348560/reduce-the-number-of-votes-required-to-close-a-question-to-4) was to reduce the number of close votes to 4. other was to make [make it more visible](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/350836/please-change-the-review-icon-back-to-a-text-link) - None of them was implemented (at least for now)

Comment: @AlonEitan No. The review icon does not change color for me. I just checked and there were 7 items on the Late Answers section (and I had no idea about it). Notifications would really help

Comment: Determining if there is a review task for *you* is extremely expensive performance wise and therefor not done.

Comment: @rene That was what I thought too at first, but all the review tasks for me are computed and displayed in the Review dropdown. So I don't think this should be that performance heavy (maybe I'm just being naive). And it could be updated just once in every 2 or 3 minutes

Comment: @AjilO, no. The dropdown shows the number of available tasks for everyone, not just yours. Read the transcript [here](https://chat.meta.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/6120590#6120590) between me and Shog9.

Comment: @rene I am actually finding it very hard to get my point across. So bear with me. Ok so right now, my drop down shows me _Late posts - 7_; _Documentation - 0_. And the _All Queues_ link which takes me to the actual Reviews page. My point is that it would be better if a notification pops up showing me that there are 7 items on the Queue. I have already exhausted my quota for *Triage* and *First Post*, which is why they don't appear in my dropdown.

Comment: For more information on when the icon changes color see [The Original Announcement](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/346653)